# Explanation of zip, reduce and combine in Swift

Tags: swift, zip, reduce, combine

Can someone please break this code example down for me? `zip` and `reduce` makes some sense, but what's going on with `combine:` is confusing me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let a = [5, 6, 7]
let b = [3, 6, 10]

let pointsAlice = zip(a, b).reduce(0, combine: { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) } )
let pointsBob = zip(b, a).reduce(0, combine: { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) } )

print("\(pointsAlice) \(pointsBob)") // 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip(a, b)` produces a sequence of tuples pairing the values from `a` and `b`

```
[(5, 3), (6, 6), (7, 10)]
```

That sequence is passed to `reduce` one tuple at a time.  `reduce` takes two parameters.  The first is the initial value for the `runningTotal`, and the second is a closure named `combine` which operates on each of the items in the sequence one call at a time.

In this case, the code is counting up the number of scores for Alice and Bob where their score is higher.

The use of default values `$0`, `$1.0`, and `$1.1` makes the code a bit hard to interpret, but here is an equivalent version:

```
let pointsAlice = zip(a, b).reduce(0, combine: { (runningTotal, scores) in
    return runningTotal + (scores.0 > scores.1 ? 1 : 0) } )
```

For each value in the sequence (such as `(5, 3)`), that value gets passed to the `combine` closure as `scores`, and the `runningTotal` gets the value from the previous iteration of `reduce`.  `scores.0` refers to the first value in the tuple, and `scores.1` refers to the second value in the tuple.  The initial `runningTotal` is the `0` that is passed to `reduce`.

The `combine` closure is returning the `runningTotal` plus `1` if the first score is higher, or plus `0` otherwise.  That value is then passed into the next call of `combine` as the new `runningTotal` value along with the next `scores` tuple.

The final result is a count of scores where the first score is higher.